# CRAM MoveIt Tutorial problem

Tags: ros, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working through the [first tutorial on using MoveIt with CRAM](http://cram-project.org/tutorials/intermediate/moveit), and I'm able to load the tutorial module, query the state of the robot, etc. without problems.

However, when I try to move the robot with the line

> (move-link-pose "r_wrist_roll_link" "right_arm" tuti:*pose-mid*)

the REPL shows

> [(MOVEIT) ERROR] 1457223557.388: Empty actionlib response.

and the MoveIt terminal window says

> [ERROR] [1457223552.356453336]: Exception thrown when deserializing message of length [5034] from [/tutorial-client]: Buffer Overrun

What might be the problem? I thought that maybe some piece of CRAM code was built against an old version of moveit_msgs, but I've tried catkin_make-ing in a clean workspace with no change.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228313/cram-moveit-tutorial-problem/) by [abestick](https://answers.ros.org/users/26180/abestick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried out the tutorial and the call succeeded for me.

Which version of `cram_moveit` and `cram_tutorials` are you using?

The link to the repository in the tutorial was a bit outdated, so I updated it now (and also cleaned up the code in the repo a bit). If you're using `cram_moveit` version 0.2.1 (see `package.xml`), then cloning from the updated link in the tutorial might help.

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abestick](https://answers.ros.org/users/26180/abestick/) on 2016-03-07**:
I was indeed using 0.2.1, and updating the cram_tutorials package as you suggested fixed it! Thanks!